# How can I tunnel multicast traffic?

Tags: tcpdump, multicast, netcat, tcpreplay

I am trying to receive multicast on 1 machine, forward it to another machine, and then replay it on that machine.

- `test_env`: the machine which has access to the original multicast stream
- `mcast_sender`: the machine which I'm trying to forward the multicast to and re-multicast from

### What I've tried so far:

Combining `tcpdump`, `netcat` and `tcpreplay` I've attempted the following:

**on `test_env`:**

I have a python script which performs an IGMP join and just sits there forever, reading from the socket and discarding the data (just keeping the socket open)

```
$ ./mcast_sub INADDR_ANY 239.194.5.1 21001 &
```

Now the interface in question will be receiving multicast data, so I can run a `tcp_dump`:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth5 host 239.194.5.1 > /tmp/capture.pcap
```

I can now run `tail` on the pcap file, and pipe it to `netcat`

```
$ tail -f /tmp/capture.pcap -n+1 | nc -l 12345
```

**on `mcast_sender`:**

On `mcast_sender` I can then receive this data from the netcat port, and dump it to a local file there:

```
$ nc test_env 12345 > /tmp/capture.pcap
```

Using `tcpreplay` I can then read the capture file on `mcast_sender` and replay it

```
$ sudo tcpreplay --intf1=eth8 /tmp/capture.pcap
```

### My problem:

The `tcpdump` - `netcat` pipeline seems to be working. I've verified that I am writing a file on `mcast_sender`.

However, when I attempt to run `tcpreplay` on it, I get an error:

```
$ sudo tcpreplay --intf1=eth8 /tmp/capture.pcap
Failed: Error opening pcap file: unknown file format
```

### Questions:

- Is it possible to do what I'm trying here?
- Why is the file written on `mcast_sender` invalid?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you need to set tcpdump's stdout to be **line buffered**

**From `man tcpdump`:**

> ```
> -l     Make stdout line buffered.  
>          Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it.  
>
>        E.g.
>             tcpdump -l | tee dat 
>             tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat
> ```

You can also do away with the intermediate file and `netcat` by piping the output of `tcpdump` directly into `tcpreplay`.

This is achieved by running the `tcpdump` over an ssh session, dumping the output to stdout, and piping that to stdin of `tcpreplay`:

*Run a command over an ssh session:*

```
$ ssh remote_server "command"
```

*Run `tcpdump` and output to stdout, line buffered:*

```
$ sudo tcpdump ... -l -w -
```

*Run `tcpreplay` reading from stdin:*

```
$ sudo tcpreplay ... -
```

**Putting it all together:**

```
$ ssh test_env "sudo tcpdump -i eth5 host 239.194.5.1 -l -w -" | 
    sudo tcpreplay --intf1=eth8 -
```